# Shared library under system/lib vs data/lib performance criteria

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I'm trying to build a system app to run custom aosp with a shared library.
There are two options to use native library loading from system/lib and loading from data/[package]/lib. But I couldn't sure whether there is a performance criteria between these two options.

When the app runs with system/lib options everything was fine but after the packaging this shared library with apk and removing from system/lib to update libraries easily, the native part of application slowed down.